# abelian groups of order $10^5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was trying to solve the following problem:

Find number of abelian groups of order $10^5$, up to isomorphism ?
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Every finite abelian group is a product of cyclic groups of prime power order.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 You mean "is isomorphic to" rather than just "is", right?

Comment: The [Structure Theorem for Finitely Generated Abelian Groups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_abelian_groups) will tell you what these groups are.

Comment: @Lovsovs If you don't mean "is isomorphic to" then you have no hope of answering a question of the number of groups of a given size: there is a proper class of trivial groups.

Comment: @Lovsovs Every finite abelian group can be expressed as an internal direct product of cyclic subgroups of prime power order, and is not merely isomorphic to such a group.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, but is that not precisely what is meant by an isomorphism? Let's say that $(G,+)=\{0,x,y,x+y\}=\{0,x\}\oplus\{0,y\}$ is abelian, where $x,y$ are of order two. Then you wouldn't write $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2,$ right? Wouldn't you rather say that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Answer (score 1):

If $n=\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{k_i}$, then the number of distinct abelian groups of order $n$ is given by
$$
\prod_{i=1}^rp(k_i),
$$
where $p(k)$ denotes the number of partitions of $k$. Now $n=10^5=2^5\cdot 5^5$, and $p(5)^2=7^2=49$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : The number of abelian groups of order $$p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$$

upto isomorphism is $$p(a_1)\cdots p(a_n)$$ where $p(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$